# Ruby on Rails 3: How can I disconnect an object from another object in the database without deleting it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

if I have the following associations...

```
class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, :through => :appointments
end

class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
end
```

I can add an existing appointment to a physician by...

```
appoint = Appointments.find(params[:id])
phys = Physician.find(params[:id])
phys.appointments << appoint
phys.save
```

but I can't figure out how to remove the appointment from the Physicians list of appointments without deleting it.  I'd like to keep the appointment in the appointments table after it's disconnected from the Physician table.

Thanks so much in advance for your wisdom!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you just set that particular `Appointment`'s `physician_id` to `nil`?

Comment: This is the easiest approach. But it wasnt clear from the question if he wanted to maintain referential integrity and/or be able to track what doctor an appointment used to be linked too. By setting it to null he loses that information. But maybe its OK. The question doesnt specify.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to remove an appointment you already have an instance of, use [collection.delete](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many):

```
phys.appointments.delete(appoint)
```

If you want to clear ALL appointments:

```
phys.appointments.clear
```

Detailed explanations about these and many other useful associations methods:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html. Look for the "Deleting from associations" section.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the soft delete approach: have another column either "deleted boolean" or "deleted_at datetime" (this one encoding two pieces of information, the fact that a record has been deleted and when).

And then in all your queries you just need to respect this: `... WHERE deleted_at IS NULL`

With Rails you can even set this as the default for all queries:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope where('deleted_at IS NULL')
end
```